# Simple Database - Design issues

Tags: database, database-design

Just a homework question I am trying to figure out, I would appreciate some assistance.

Apparently, there are three problems with the design of this database design:

```
Account = {AccNumber, Type, Balance}
Customer = {CustID, FirstName, LastName, Address, AccNumber}
```

The one that is pretty obvious is that 'CustID' is useless if 'AccNumber' exists.

I am not quite sure about the second and third problem.

Is there a problem with a separate attribute for 'FirstName' and "LastName', cant we just use 'Name'?

And another option, if 'AccNumber' is the primary key (assuming CustID will be removed), it probably should be place in the beginning :

Such as:

```
Customer = {AccNumber, Name, Address}
```

Any input would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The customer-account relationship, at first glance, appears to be a many-many relationship, which necessitates the use of an intermediary relationship table.  For instance, I have three accounts of my own at my bank.  In addition, my wife has two of her own.  Finally, we have a shared account.  The schema above could not well handle such relationships.

You could, indeed, just use "Name" - but you may need to know what the first or last names are at some point in the future and such a concatination can be quite problematic to split.

Good luck with your homework...

Comment: -1 for making assumptions as in @tyjkenn's answer, but +1 for addressing his question about the name.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you haven't presented us with what the database should represent in words; as it is now, there's nothing "wrong" with the design, since we don't know what the design is supposed to model.

I certainly wouldn't say that `CustID` is useless, as it serves as the primary key of the table. What you need to determine is the relationship between customers and accounts. It should be one of the following:

1. A single customer can be tied to multiple accounts, but a single account can be tied to a single customer
2. A single customer can be tied to only one account, but an account can be tied to multiple customers.
3. A single customer can be tied to multiple accounts, and a single account can be tied to multiple customers

Right now, with `AccNumber` in the `Customer` table, your design models #2.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The only additional piece of useful information mentioned in the assignment is that this table is used for a 'bank account'.

Comment: I suppose more appropriate setup would be to eliminate the ‘AccNumber’ for the Customer field, and add an extra table : CustomerAccounts = { CustID, AccNumber}.  The new account table would be as such: Account = {AccNumber, Type, Balance}.

Comment: @GregorioDiStefano: This only makes sense if either an account makes sense *not* attached to a customer *or* an account can be attached to multiple customers. If neither is true (meaning that an account is attached to exactly one customer), then you should have a `CustId` column in the `Account` table.

Comment: I would argue there is something "wrong" with the design.  The AccNumber field existing in two tables as described breaks any kind of normalization you might want to apply.

Comment: @Rob: In what way? The presented design is perfectly acceptable if there exists a relationship between `Customer` and `Account` such that a single customer is associated with a single account and a single account can be associated with 0-n customers. In other words, if `AccNumber` is the PK of the `Account` table and a FK from `Customer` to `Account`.

Comment: @Adam:  If the design represents #2, the Customer data would be duplicated for every distinct account; not normalized.  This schema represents a 1:1 relationship between customers and accounts, and IMHO, splitting that between two tables is "wrong" unless there is a very good reason to not do so.

Comment: @Rob: On what basis do you claim that a single account cannot be associated with more than one customer (and that's it's furthermore 1:1 and not 0-1:0-1)?

Comment: @Adam: My apologies; I read your statement more closely and threw out any assumptions about what the actual use would look like and see, indeed, an account could have multiple owners in the above schema.

Answer (score 0):

How is is designed right now, each customer could only have one bank account.

The many-to-many relationship will be a problem. Instead, you might create a third table that holds the relationships. For example:

```
Account = {AccNumber, Type, Balance}
Connection = {ConnID, AccNumber, CustID}
Customer = {CustID, FirstName, LastName, Address}
```

This way, both Account and Customer are parented by Connection (for lack of a better name). You could query all connections with a certain AccNumber and find all the customers using that account, and vice versa.

Comment: ConnID is redundant.  The primary key in such a table can be AccNumber and CustID together; you don't want any duplicate CustID-AcctNumber relationships.

Comment: -1 only because this makes assumptions about the requirements (namely that there should exist a M:M relationship between `Customer` and `Account`) that are unfounded. While the assumption might be correct (we don't know), the question gives no indication that this is so.